# Is there a formula for correcting RGB in an image based on a sample within the image?

Tags: rgb, photoshop, gimp

In a photo I have the following:

- position 1,1: red (255,0,0)
- position 1,2: green (0,255,0)
- position 1,3: blue (0,0,255)
- position 1,4: white (255,255,255)
- position 1,5: black (0,0,0)

If in the photo these values come back differently than expected, for example, position 1,1 is `rgb(144, 20, 10)` and I know it should be `rgb(255,0,0)` then...

1. How do I calculate how much to correct my red values in the image
2. Would I use a feature such as Color Balance in an editor to apply the corrections

Comment: I think in the Gimp and Photoshop world, Channel Mixer is what I am looking for❓

Comment: Are you maybe saving your file as a JPEG, which is lossy and allowed to change your pixels? Maybe try lossless PNG.

Comment: Not only JPEG is "lossy", on compression, but also not full colour data is saved for every pixels (and this is not considered "lossy", but you lose much information). But to answer: just scale (better in linear space), but it needs human feedback, so use real programs. Argyllcms could be used to create profiles/LUT tables and so to convert automatically (but it is a complex topic, as you see in the extreme long documentation of the numerous tools)